# Removing Ionic slider pager when only one slide

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am looking to hide the Ionic slider pager when there is only one slide within the slider. I found this thread at the Ionic forums https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-hide-slide-pager-slide-box-when-item-only-has-1-image-and-show-when-has-more/49886/2 and I tried it out but I think it must be for Ionic v1 or v2 as it through up an error for me in Ionic v3.

Is there any particular conditional or method I can use to hide pagination if there is only one image slide?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<ion-slides #imageSlides [pager]=“imageSlides.length() > 1”>
```

pager is an attribute that is boolean. You need to check length of your slides or do that via your model length.